# F# filtering sublist

Tags: list, filter, f#

Here is an input list: `[[10;2;10]; [10;50;10]; [10;1;10]]`.

How would I filter the second element of each sub-list?

Below is my code and when I output the result I get `[[10;50;10]]` but what I want is `[2;50;1]`. Is there anyway to fix my code? I am really trying to understand F#. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
let sub =

     let input = [[10;2;10]; [10;50;10]; [10;1;10]]
     let findIndex input elem = input |> List.findIndex ((=) elem)
     let q = input |> List.filter(fun elem -> findIndex input elem = 1)
     printfn "%A" q
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will get the expected result:

```
let second (x:List<int>) = x.[1]
let q = List.map second input
```

[`List.map`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/list.map%5B't,'u%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) is a higher order function that makes a new list by applying a function (the first argument, here the function `second` that returns the second element of a list) to a list (here `input`):

```
[ [10;2;10]; [10;50;10]; [10;1;10] ]
       |          |          |
    second     second      second       <--- mapping function
       |          |          |
       V          V          V
[     2    ;     50    ;     1    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use List.map, not List.filter

List.filter keeps/removes items from an input list based on the function you give it, e.g. `List.filter (fun x -> x % 2 = 0) myList` would keep only the even numbers in `myList`. You can get an idea of this functionality based on its type signature, which is `val filter: ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list`, meaning it takes a function (that takes an 'a and returns a boolean: `('a -> bool)`), then takes a list, and returns a list of the same type.

List.map, on the other hand, transforms each element of a list into whatever you want, based on a function you give it. In your case you would use it like so:

```
let input = [[10;2;10]; [10;50;10]; [10;1;10]]
let result = input |> List.map (fun numbers -> numbers.[1])
printfn "%A" result
```

The signature of `List.map` is `val map: ('a -> 'b) -> 'a list -> 'b list`, meaning it takes a function that maps `'a`s to `'b`s (in your case, this would map `int list`s to `int`s), takes a list of the first thing, and returns a list of the second thing.

### Use List.map *and* List.tryIndex

Note that if any of the sub-lists are too short, the program will crash. If this is a concern, you can use a safe version of `myList.[i]`; namely `List.tryIndex`, which returns None if the item was not found. Try this out:

```
// Note the last sublist
let input = [[10;2;10]; [10;50;10]; [10;1;10]; [-1]]
let result : int option list = input |> List.map (fun numbers -> List.tryIndex 1 numbers)
printfn "%A" result
// This prints:
// [Some 2; Some 50; Some 1; None]
```